# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. Generic method to get entity by ID

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In CRM 4.0 I had the generic method in my repository:

```cs
public T GetEntityById(Guid id)
{
    var entities =
        from e in m_context.GetEntities(typeof (T).Name)
        where e.GetPropertyValue<Guid>(IdentityFieldName) == id
        select e;
    return (T) entities.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

But what about CRM 2011? `ICrmEntity` with GetPropertyValue method is missed...

What is alternate to get generic entity by ID?

Comment: What's m_context in this instance? Is it of type ServiceContext? Also, is this method going to sit in some form of repository class specific for the entity? E.g. declared as Repository<Account> or something?

Answer (score 0):

something like `(T) m_context.Retrieve(typeof (T).Name, id, new ColumnSet())`.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when looking for the same answer, this is how I ended up solving it.

```
    public T GetEntityByID<T>(Guid guid) where T : Entity
    {
        return (T) (_organizationService.Retrieve((typeof(T)).Name, guid, new ColumnSet()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You really want to be using the ToEntity method, rather than casting.  Sometimes the typeof(T).Name will have capitalization differences, so I wrote a helper funciton as well:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Retrieves the Entity of the given type with the given Id, with the given columns
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">An early bound Entity Type</typeparam>
/// <param name="service">open IOrganizationService</param>
/// <param name="id">Primary Key of Entity</param>
/// <param name="columnSet">Columns to retrieve</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static T GetEntity<T>(this IOrganizationService service, Guid id, ColumnSet columnSet)
    where T : Entity
{
    return service.Retrieve(EntityHelper.GetEntityLogicalName<T>(), id, columnSet).ToEntity<T>()
}

public static string GetEntityLogicalName<T>() where T : Entity
{
    return GetEntityLogicalName(typeof(T));
}

public static string GetEntityLogicalName(Type type)
{
    var field = type.GetField("EntityLogicalName");
    if (field == null)
    {
        if (type == typeof(Entity))
        {
            return "entity";
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Type " + type.FullName + " does not contain an EntityLogicalName Field");
        }
    }
    return (string)field.GetValue(null);
}
```